# How to use a css file for a specific page in drupal 7?

Tags: css, drupal-7

i would like to use a css file in drupal 7 for a specific page and i would like to cancel the default theme for this page.

I use the method called drupal_add_css it's working but this method doesn't permit to cancel the defautl theme

Help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module to configure which theme is displayed for which page.  If you set the theme for the page you want to cancel the default theme for to `Stark` (the no-frills no-style theme included as part of core in D7), you will be able to use just your css via `drupal_add_css()`.

Comment: You can use the Features module to keep your configuration in code.  You could alternately just make a static html file outside of Drupal; if it's only one page of static content, that would be faster.